# Laravel contact form with related models

Tags: php, laravel

I have a create patient page with few tabs which are all part of a model related to the `Patient`. Related model is for example `DentalPlan`, and the way it works now is to forward all the data (both patient and dental plan related) to the controller, with the minor exception that the dental plan data is forwarded like an array so I can group it in the request input:

```
{{ Form::text('dental_plan[card_number]', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

The problem is that I can't utilize form reusage this way because there is no way to forward saved related model this way. Is there some way I can do it for example:

```
{{ Form::text( $patient->dental_plan->card_number, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: can you paste the code of form file, store and edit method?

Comment: Is the relationship type a hasOne or a hasMany?

Comment: One patient can have many dental plans